# grub file updation failed in sles12

Tags: azure, linux-kernel, grub, sles

working on SLES12SP3 kdump configuration hosted on MICROSOFT-AZURE. Trying to start the kdump service but grub file is not getting updated with crash kernel parameter in /etc/default/grub crashkernel=384M.
ERROR:

```
Starting Load kdump kernel and initrd...
Memory for crashkernel is not reserved   
Please reserve memory by passing"crashkerne
Then try to loading kdump kernelkexec_file_
kdump.service: Main process exited, code=exite
Failed to start Load kdump kernel and initrd.
kdump.service: Unit entered failed state.
kdump.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you update the grub after changing crash kernel bootarg settings? Does "crashkernel=384M" appear in kernel command line? What does /proc/cmdline show when you are booted with kdump enabled images?

Comment: thanks for the response. Rebooted the vm after changing bootarg settings but i did not get crashkernel=384M in /proc/cmdline output.

Answer (score -1):

finally i updated the grub file by executing below command

```
#grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2//grub.cfg
```

After rebooting when i ran the command cat /proc/cmdline it displayed crash kernel parameter like below

> earlyprintk=ttyS0 console=ttyS0 rootdelay=300 net.ifnames=0
>   ***crashkernel=384M*** dis_ucode_ldr quiet